# Is there an inseparable subset of the complex plane?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Is there an inseparable subset of the complex plane ?I proved that all separable subsets form a sigma-algebra,and a rectangle is obviously separable, so a counter example would not a Borel set.

Comment: A set forming a $\sigma -$ algbra has no meaning.

Comment: I mean all separable subsets form a sigma-algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every subset of a separable metric space is separable in the induced metric.

Comment: Moreover, every separable metric space is second countable, and every subspace os a second countable space is second countable and therefore separable.

Comment: thank you.......